# Node reference URL in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes

How can I make a node reference URL visible only to the person who created the page/article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by setting the appropriate permissions. For Drupal 6, content_permissions is part of CCK, and lets you set permission for every CCK field of your content type. For Drupal 7 you can use the [Field Permission](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

Comment: sometimes I soooooo overthink things :)

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, I just looked at this and assumed you are talking about Views. I don't know why.
In any case, this may or may not make any sense.

You will obviously have to put some PHP around it that checks if `$node->uid == $user->uid` and output the field only if true.

In Drupal 6, I'd do that in the Views template that formats that field. I find that information out by looking at what templates Views uses for the view from the Styles Settings/Theme Information links.

Drupal 7 does all sort of things differently, but the Views Module there does have similar templates; whether or not this is best practice, there or not I am not one to say, but this should set you on one path of how to do it.

**EDIT:** If this is just a field in a node you want formatted differently, look at system module field/theme/field.tpl.php and do the above in there (copying it of course).